# Javascript issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question regarding my button disappear

I've put an image as my button

```
<div id="button1">
   <a href="javascript:example_animate('-=200px')">
      <img src="images/button1.jpeg">
   </a>
</div>
```

that is animated with this function

```
<script language="javascript">
function example_animate(px) {
    $('#content2').animate({
        'marginTop' : px
    });
}
</script>
```

and i can't get it disappear after doing this function with this script

```
<script language="javascript">
$("#button1").click(function () {
   this.visible = false;
});
</script>
```

please help!

Comment: Have you tried `this.style.display = 'none';` ?

Answer (score 4):

since you're already using jquery , just do

```
$("#button1").hide();
```

to hide the button.  http://api.jquery.com/hide/

What you should have done to hide it the DOM way was to either set `element.style.visibility='hidden';`

OR

```
element.style.display='none';
```

Both calls will hide the element , but changing the visibility means the element will still occupy the screen space.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
this.visible = false;
```

try:

```
this.style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#button1").click(function () {
    this.style.display = "none";
});
```

Comment: When i put this code, the button disappears the second time you click on it..how can i make it disappear the first time you click on it.here is the code:<script language="javascript">
 $("#button1").click(function () {
    this.style.display = "none";
});
}
</script>